# Recover partitions after ‘diskutil partitionDisk’ command

Tags: hard-drive, macos, filevault, data-recovery

I accidentally repartitioned my main storage hard drive, by using the following terminal command on it:

```
diskutil partitionDisk disk2 GPT JHFS+ "Canvio" 0g
```

The hard drive has about 3 TB of data on it, everything that I need. Is there any way to get this data back by just simply re-creating the partitions? Meaning will software out there restore the partition table? The original hard drive had two partitions: one for data and one for Time Machine backups.

I have the following software: Disk Drill and Stellar Phoenix Mac data recovery. I could scan the whole hard drive for its content copy that to a new hard drive and copy it back, but I was wondering if there is any other easier way of doing this, where the partitions can just be re-created on the same hard drive.

I am running 10.12.6

**To make matters worse I just realized the drive might have also been encrypted with FileVault 2.  Any chances for recovery now?**

Comment: The problem is **not** the partition table (which can be restored easily) but the overwritten meta-data of the first partition. It's rather difficult to describe this, so I usually ask to d/l TeamViewer and invite me to remote desktop session!

Comment: I have teamViewer. How can we trade information for you to help? I saw your reply to another post with a similar issue it seemed to help out there. Thanks  alot!